# Javascript on firebase signup how can I save displayName, or photoURL?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to save FullName and Profile Picture while signing up to firebase but after SignIn it returns null the user.displayName and user.photoURL values. I tried as below, this is how firebase docs show. (New version of firebase `authuser.user.update()` doesn't work. )

```
    const signUp = () => {
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
            user.email = email
            user.displayName = name;
            user.photoURL = photo;
        }).catch((error) => {
            const errmessage = erro.message;
            alert(errmessage);
        })
        navigation.navigate("Home")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with   `updateProfile(user, {displayName: name, photoURL: photo})`

Now it keeps the FullName and Photo even after logout.

Here is my fullcode:

```
  const signUp = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        updateProfile(user, {displayName: name, photoURL: photo})
    }).catch((error) => {
        const errmessage = erro.message;
        alert(errmessage);
    })
    navigation.navigate("Giriş Yap")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should move your user creation to a backend server, you can use firebase cloud functions and use [Firebase Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?hl=pt-br#create_a_user) to create and manage your users. You'll have much more control on user managemen.

With Admin SDK you can create a new user as shown below:

```
const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
  email: 'your@email.com',
  password: 'abc123',
  emailVerified: false/true,
  displayName: 'Any Name',
  photoURL: 'https://....',
  disabled: false
})
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for that I already solved it but your solution also seems good.